# What is the sampling rate of quarterly time series data?

Tags: r, time-series, spectral-analysis

I am doing spectral analysis of quarterly data. I am very new to spectral analysis and have been using Shumway & Stoffer's textbook as a guide, but I am not understanding exactly what is going on.

I have quarterly data with a trend and seasonal component:

[image: decomposed time series]

I have removed the increasing trend from my data and calculated the periodogram:

```
detrend <- target - decompose(target)$trend
detrend<-na.omit(detrend)

sp2=spectrum(detrend,log="no",main="",ylab="Spectrum",xlab="Freqeuncy")
```

[image: periodogram]

Im slightly confused as to how to interpret the periodogram. The frequency axis is in terms of cycles per sampling interval correct? Is the sampling interval a year? So the peak at a frequency of 1 is indicating one cycle per year?